# Internal Implementation of TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, treemap

how internal Implementation of TreeMap is done in Java? Does it use any tree (like : binary tree, red-black, B-tree) for arranging elements?

Comment: Source code is your friend :)

Comment: Red-black. It's in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). On the first line.

Answer (score 3):

First line of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> A Red-Black tree based `NavigableMap` implementation.